# 'Open .bash_profile' conflict on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, files

I want to edit `.bash_profile` on my Ubuntu system. When I try to run the command `open .bash_profile`, it gives this message:

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Please help me get around this problem and edit the file.

Comment: You should be able to just do something like `vim ~/.bash_profile`. If you can't, then you have probably borked the file's permissions or something.

Answer (score 4):

`open(1)` is a symlink to `openvt(1)`, for which the description is "start a program on a new virtual terminal". To do this, it needs access to the console device to open the virtual terminal. This is not likely the program you are looking for.

Debian systems have a generic `edit` command that you can use to edit a file. Otherwise, choose a specific editor you want to use and invoke that with `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a very simple way: go to your home folder and go to view in the menu bar, check the show hidden files option and now you will be able to see the folders and files starting with  a dot (.). Now find yourself a .bash_profile. If found , do your thing, and if not, well create one and then do your thing. I created me one but it was .bash_aliases (to store an alias for zend framework command line operation). It's simple.